# python - Is it possible to convert a string and put it into a list [] containing tuple ()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example, these two are the strings and they are separated by tabs.

`2012-01-01 09:00   San Jose    Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex`

Is it possible to convert string to list [] containing tuple () :

```
[("2012-01-01", "09:00",    "San Jose", "Men's Clothing",   "214.05",   "Amex")]
```

If so, how can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

edit: Changed title

Comment: This is not a dictionary, this is list [] containing tuple () i.e [( )]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a list of elements:

```
a = "2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex"
print [i for i in a.split("    ")]
```

**Result:**

```
['2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex']
```

*or if it is a list of tuple:*

```
a = "2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex"
print [tuple(i for i in a.split("    "))]
```

**Result:**

```
[('2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex')]
```

*And if you have multiple line of the string:*

```
a = """2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex
2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex
2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex
2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex
2012-01-01 09:00    San Jose    Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex"""


print [tuple(j.split("    ")) for j in a.split("\n")]
```

**Result:**

```
[('2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), ('2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), ('2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), ('2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), ('2012-01-01 09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex')]
```

Comment: isn't it simpler to use a.split() instead of adding a filter?

Comment: oh, I see now, it is a tab

Comment: thank you very much! May i ask what does the `j` mean in this `print [tuple(j.split("    ")) for j in a.split("\n")]`

Comment: j represents each element in a list. this will help explain more https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted, I suppose you have a newline-separated string of tab-separated values. Hence, first we translate this string into a list of tab-separated values, and then translate each into tuples.

```
result = [tuple(line.split('\t')) for line in original.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the string_given is the string you are giving as input and output_string is the output u need to get in the following piece of code...

there may be a tons of methods but i have used normal splitting and deleting the elements...please let me know if i am wrong

```
string_given= " 2012-01-01 09:00   San Jose    Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex"
output_string=list(string_given.strip().split())
output_string[2]=str.join(' ',(output_string[2],output_string[3]))
del output_string[3]
output_string[3]=str.join(' ',(output_string[3],output_string[4]))
del output_string[4]
print(output_string)
```

Result

```
['2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex']
```

for making the output as tuple

```
tupled_string=tuple(output_string)
print([tupled_string])
```

Result is

```
[('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have one more question, if i have more than one of those strings, how can i insert the string into another tuple in the same list

Comment: since tuples are immutable you cannot modify a tuple after it is created you can only replace it...refer this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) at the lines **bold** Tuples are immutable, and usually contain a heterogeneous sequence of elements **bold**  ping me back if it still did not clarify your doubt @Bryan