# Using split to read specific string from a line in a file

Tags: python, string, file, split

Given the text file

**sample.txt**

```
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   Men's Clothing    214.05    Amex
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   Women's Clothing  153.57    Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   Omaha       Music             66.08     Cash
```

I want to be able to read only the text for the third column. This code

```
for line in open("sample.txt"):
      city=line.split()[2]
      print(city)
```

can read the third column to a certain degree:

```
San
San
Omaha
```

but what I want is:

```
San Diego
San Diego
Omaha
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You need to specify what substring splits your string. Something like: `split("\t")`. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/743807/3103891)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Is it possible to convert a string and put it into a list \[\] containing tuple ()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335590/python-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-string-and-put-it-into-a-list-containing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like your file is separated by tabs (or \t).

Have you tried splitting it by tabs ?

Instead of `city=line.split()[2]` try `city=line.split('\t')[2]`.

Anyways, it looks like this file has been generated by an excel or similar, have you tried exporting it to a CSV (comma separated values) format, instead of pure txt ?

Then you can simply split by commas, like `city=line.split(',')[2]`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It appears your input file has fixed width fields. You might be able to achieve your goal using indexing in this case, e.g.

```
>>> for line in open('test.txt'):
...     print(line[20:32])
...
San Diego
San Diego
Omaha
```

You could add a `.strip()` to trim off trailing spaces if you need that for further processing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file delimits with at least two spaces, so specifying to split on two spaces and stripping away the remaining spaces on the ends with strip() works.

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        city=line.split('  ')[2].strip()
        print(city)
```

yields:

```
San Diego
San Diego
Omaha
```

Comment: We don't know that it's guaranteed to leave at least two spaces between columns. What happens if the 3rd column contains a city 11 letters long? I suspect you'd get a single space before the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Since your items in `sample.txt` are mostly separated by 2 spaces, you need to use `split('  ')` instead. If you use `split()`, this will by default split every whitespace, such as turning `"Men's Clothing"` into `["Men's", "Clothing"]`, Which is not what you want.

First thing you can do is view your items with:

```
with open('sample.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file.readlines():
        items = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split('  ') if x]
        print(items)
```

Which outputs:

```
['2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Diego', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex']
['2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Diego', "Women's Clothing", '153.57', 'Visa']
['2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Omaha', 'Music', '66.08', 'Cash']
```

Now if you want to extract the third column:

```
print(items[2])
```

Which gives:

```
San Diego
San Diego
Omaha
```

Comment: There might be cases where the gap between columns is only one space.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to preprocess your input file by adding a delimeter which you will specify in your `split()` function. Like this:

```
2012-01-01,  09:00,   San Diego,   Men's Clothing,    214.05,    Amex
2012-01-01,  09:00,   San Diego,   Women's Clothing,  153.57,    Visa
2012-01-01,  09:00,   Omaha,       Music,             66.08,     Cash
```

Then

```
for line in open("sample.txt"):
  city=line.split(",")[2]
  print(city)
```

Comment: Then how do you know where to put the commas? You're just pushing the hard part of the question on to someone else.